# Bing map infowindow limitation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-maps

I am using Bing map in one of my project to show the vehicle as push pins. The issue that I am facing is that whenever the number of push pins goes more than 100 (I am not sure at this figure though), it does not show any push pins on the map and the browser shows an error:

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".**

And when I retry in the same scenario by passing blank string in the infowindow, all goes well. Currently there are some 400+ push pins on the map and the condition is same as I stated above, i.e., if I am not passing anything in infowindow, it shows all push pins but if I try to show details in infowindow (which is the requirement in the project), it does not show any push pins and shows the above error.

Please help me in this.

I am using the following C# code in a loop for creating a table for the infowindow for each pushpin:

```
            string InfoWindow = "<table class='table' style='font-size:9px;'>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Shipment</b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["shipmentcode"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Origin </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Origin"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Destination </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Destination"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Current Location </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Date and Time </b></td><td>" + Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["dt_tracker"].ToString().Trim()).ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Driver </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["DriverName"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Contact No. </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["DriverNumber"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Speed </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Speed"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td><b>Status </b></td><td>" + dt.Rows[i]["FinalStatus"].ToString().Trim() + "<td></tr>" +
                     "</table>";
```

and then I am creating JSON (MarkersData in the code below) and then I am showing pushpins on the ASPX page:

```
var vehicles = [];
vehicles = JSON.parse(MarkersData);
for (i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {

            var data = vehicles[i];
            var iconPath= '../images/vehicles/'+col+'/truck.png';
            var pinName= 'pin'+i.toString();
            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data.lat, data.lng), {icon: iconPath, typeName: pinName});


            tooltip = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pin.getLocation(), {
                visible: false,
                showPointer: false,
                showCloseButton: false,
                offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-75, 10)
            });
            tooltip.setMap(map);

            //Create an infobox for displaying detailed information.
            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pin.getLocation(), {
                visible: false
            });
            infobox.setMap(map);

            pin.metadata = {
                title: data.title,
                description: data.infowindow
            };
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', VehiclepinHovered);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseout', closeTooltip);

            map.entities.push(pin);


        }
```

**Push pins are showing without any issues with infowindow too, when the numbers of pushpins are less. The problem arises when this number goes up.**